# Invalid regular expression nothing to repeat for validating credit card number type

Tags: javascript, validation, syntax-error, credit-card

I've the following regular expression used for validating credit card number type using javascript

`var match = /^(?:(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)|(5[1-5][0-9]{14})|?(6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12})|(3[47][0-9]{13})|(3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])?[0-9]{11})|((?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{11}))$/.exec(cardno);`

Previously this code was running perfectly but now it shows the above error. Can anyone check it out and make any changes?

Comment: Where is the "above error" ?

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be using the LUHN test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

```
/*
mod10( cardNumber )
   parameters:
      this function takes the text string card number and runs the Mod 10 formula on its respective digits.
   description:
      Mod 10 is the check digit formula for the supported cards these functions attempt to validate.
   returns:
      this function returns true if the number passes the check digit test.
      false otherwise.
*/
function mod10( cardNumber ) { // LUHN Formula for validation of credit card numbers.
   var ar = new Array( cardNumber.length );
   var i = 0,sum = 0;

   for( i = 0; i < cardNumber.length; ++i ) {
      ar[i] = parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i));
   }
   for( i = ar.length -2; i >= 0; i-=2 ) { // you have to start from the right, and work back.
      ar[i] *= 2;                      // every second digit starting with the right most (check digit)
      if( ar[i] > 9 ) ar[i]-=9;          // will be doubled, and summed with the skipped digits.
   }                               // if the double digit is > 9, ADD those individual digits together 

   for( i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i ) {
      sum += ar[i];                   // if the sum is divisible by 10 mod10 succeeds
   }
   return (((sum%10)==0)?true:false);       
}
```

Comment: The luhn check (last digit) is is arguably an additional check. The questioner is attempting to validate the IIN (first six digits). Attempting to validate IIN without understanding that the IIN ranges change frequently will always be prone to error though

Comment: i need to check card type only...?

Answer (score 0):

enter it on http://www.regex101.com and it will tell you that the question mark in this chunk: `14})|?(6(` should be removed, because the question mark means that the preceeding token is optional, yet it is preceded by the or operator which is not a token. Note that this is different from `?:` which denotes a non capturing group.